# how to add overall collider to a bunch of circles or boxes?

Tags: unity, 2d, collider

I have 3 circles (2D)  they all have circleCollider2D. what I want is to make a collider that make border around them. I can't express which type of collider I need, so I put example image below. Red lines are the collider I want.
[image]

Comment: A collider won't create a visible border. Do you want a visible border, or do you want a collider? Try explaining how you're using this in your game - how should the player interact with it - as this can help clear up any ambiguities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [PolygonCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PolygonCollider2D.html). It allows you to create a collider with any shape you want.

Another option which is less flexible but might be more performant in your particular case could be to create a [CompositeCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CompositeCollider2D.html) and a Rigidbody2D and then create three child game-objects, each one with a BoxCollider with "Used by Composite" enabled.

Update by Rashad:
I used Polygon collider to solve the problem. You can see image below
[image]

Comment: It worked. I did know that how polygon collider works. but I didn't think that I can use it the way I want. Thank you man. I add photo to your answer. I used it now. Thank you